# invalid use of group in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I have the following query:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->select('DISTINCT s.username') 
                ->addSelect('COUNT(p.id) as HIDDEN c_id')
                ->leftJoin('s.owner', 'o')
                ->leftJoin('s.userPictures', 'p')
                ->leftJoin('o.transactions', 't')
                ->leftJoin('t.packType', 'pt')
                ->where('pt.id =:packId')
                ->setParameter('packId', $packId)
                ->andWhere('s.expirydate >=:expiryDate')
                ->setParameter('expiryDate', new \DateTime('now'))
                ->andWhere('COUNT(p.id) <:numberOfPictures')
                ->setParameter('numberOfPictures', $numberOfPictures)
                ->groupBy('p.shop')
                ->orderBy("c_id", 'ASC')
                ->getQuery()
                ->getResult()
                ;
```

however when trying to run this I always get invalid use of group function. Why is this?

Here's the real SQL query when translated:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.username, COUNT(p.id) as HIDDEN c_id 
FROM App\MainBundle\Entity\InstagramShop s 
    LEFT JOIN s.owner o 
    LEFT JOIN s.userPictures p 
    LEFT JOIN o.transactions t 
    LEFT JOIN t.packType pt 
WHERE pt.id =:packId AND s.expirydate >=:expiryDate AND COUNT(p.id) <:numberOfPictures 
GROUP BY p.shop 
ORDER BY c_id ASC
```

Comment: Put `GROUP BY` clause before `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: orderby cluase  Comes last

Comment: Rearrange your query structure and try to run it.

Comment: i tried that and it still gives me the same error

Comment: Call `getSql()` after `getQuery()` and post the raw mysql query generated by doctrine so we can see real query and usage of group by

Comment: In the basic structure of query, it is not possible to use a single `GROUP BY` clause with one or more join conditions.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid okay just did